# How to get column value and average in the same row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table tbl structure having

```
col1  col2    col3

1       10     3
2       20     3
3       30     4
4       40     4
```

Need to get output as

```
col2    col3  Avg

10      3     15
20      3     15
30      4     35
40      4     35
```

So basically I need average on col3.
I tried

```
select col2,col3,avg(col2) from tbl1 group by col3
```

But this would only give us the first row in each matching group.

How to get this done in mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select tbl1.col2, tbl1.col3, tbl2.avgcol2 
from tbl1
inner join
(
   select col3,avg(col2) as avgcol2
   from tbl1 
   group by col3
) tbl2 on tbl1.col3 = tbl2.col3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, my tbl1 is actually a subquery in itself. Now I am unable to refer that using alias, and executing the same twice won't be good. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery on your SELECT:

```
select t1.col2,
       t1.col3,
       (select avg(t2.col2) from tab1 t2 where t2.col3 = t1.col3)  AS AVERAGE
FROM tab1 t1
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98a91/5)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot, Please refer to my comment on @juergen's answer. Any suggestion there.

Comment: According to your suggestion my query would look like : `select t1.col2, t2.col3, (select avg(t2.col3) from t1 where t1.col3=col3 ) as average from (select ....) t1`

Comment: That is trickier. You could try to do this in your subquery to check the original tables and then you would do t1.average just once in the query above.